# Unable to install python module paramiko successfully on mac

Tags: python, ssh, client, paramiko, transport

1)Installed paramiko on mac, but getting some different errors.

**pip install paramiko**

```
Requirement already satisfied: paramiko in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pynacl>=1.0.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from paramiko)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.7 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from paramiko)
Requirement already satisfied: bcrypt>=3.1.3 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from paramiko)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=1.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from paramiko)
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pynacl>=1.0.1->paramiko)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.4.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pynacl>=1.0.1->paramiko)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko)
Requirement already satisfied: ipaddress in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.4.1->pynacl>=1.0.1->paramiko)
```

Open the terminal, type python. Now in python prompt, **import paramiko**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 57, in <module>
    from paramiko.ed25519key import Ed25519Key
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paramiko/ed25519key.py", line 22, in <module>
    import nacl.signing
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nacl/signing.py", line 19, in <module>
    import nacl.bindings
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nacl/bindings/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from nacl.bindings.crypto_box import (
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nacl/bindings/crypto_box.py", line 18, in <module>
    from nacl._sodium import ffi, lib
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nacl/_sodium.so, 2): Symbol not found: _crypto_box
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nacl/_sodium.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nacl/_sodium.so
```

2) After trying some different options, tried `sudo -H pip install paramiko` and `import paramiko` from python prompt didn't result into any error.

But when executed paramiko login snippet, resulted into an error **Client.py and transport.py & module error certificate transparency**

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is exactly. Are you still seeing the ImportError you wrote above, or is it gone and can you successfully run a paramiko application but are you getting the "certificate transparency" error instead?  If the latter please change your question to actually include the relevant error traceback and the "login snippet" that causes it

Comment: Duplicate as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45206287/python-2-7-paramiko-symbol-not-found-crypto-box

Comment: @IrmendeJong : Overcame "import paramiko" error by installing paramiko in this way, "sudo -H pip install". But now getting "certificate transparency" error for running a login snippet. is something wrong with python path ?

Comment: please update your question title and question text then, because it is no longer an *installation* problem.  The "certificate transparency" error is something that I don't know about other than that it is a feature of ssh itself so probably there's a problem with your ssh certificates